# I am making a function to detect input types in Python and I can't make it work

Tags: python, input

So I am making a prime number detector as a project. I’m VERY new to programming and my friend showed me a little python. I want to make a function that detects if the user puts in a number for the input (like 5,28,156,42,63) and if the put in something else (like banana,pants,or cereal) to give them a custom error saying "Invalid Number. Please Try Again" and then looping the program until they put in a number.

Please help me make this work.

```
def number_checker():
    user_number = int(input('Please enter a Number: '))
    check = isinstance(user_number, int)
    if check == True:
        print ('This is a number')
    if check == False:
        print ('This is not a number')
```

Comment: You must try yourself first

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: We are not going to code for you. We can only try to answer questions about your code

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added the source code.

Answer (score 1):

1) Casting input to `int` would raise an exception if the input string cannot be converted to `int`.

```
user_number = int(input('Please enter a Number: '))
              ^^^
```

2) It does not make sense to cross-verify `user_number`  with `int` instance as it would already be `int`
3) You can try

```
def number_checker():                          
    while not input("enter num: ").isdigit():  
        print("This is not a number")          
    print("This is a number")                  
number_checker()
```

Comment: Call `number_checker()` again? This is not a task for recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
def number_checker():
    msg = 'Put your number > '
    while True:
        user_input = input(msg)
        correct = user_input.isdigit()
        if correct:
            print("This is an integer")
            return  # here you can put int(user_input) 
        else:
            print("This is not an integer")
            msg = 'You typed not integer. Try again.> '

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_checker()
```

And it's also good rule give names for your functions as verbs according to what they do. For this one, I would give, for example `def int_input` or something.